# Two player coin game : tracing optimal sequence in dynamic programming

Tags: java, algorithm, memory, runtime, dynamic-programming

Two players take turns choosing one of the outer coins. At the end we calculate the difference between the score two players get, given that they play optimally. for example the list{4,3,2,1},
the optimal sequence would be 4, 3, 2, 1. then i will get 4+2 = 6 scores and the opponent 4 scores.
Now i have developed an algorithm as follow: [image]

My Job is to print the scores out, and also the optimal sequence in index. so in the array {4,3,2,1} the optimal sequence would be 0,1,2,3.

The maximum Runtime and Memory should not exceed n^2.
Therefore I implemented the above algorithm with bottom up approach,which means in an i*j table, according to my algorithm, subproblems are solved one by one until the only main problem, which locates at the top right corner(where i =0 and j = n-1). It works calculating the scores, but i have no idea how to trace the optimal sequence during runtime, since when I calculate subproblems by subproblems, only the score will be save and used in the next problem, while the sequence, which led to the final result, is hard to trace back.

I tried to create Pairs or multidimensional ArrayList to record the sequences and their corresponding memo[i][j]...... Well, they worked, but the memory needed would then be greater than n^2 and this is not allowed in my task.

So, does anymore have a better idea that does not require that much memory space?

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

My code:

```
public int maxGain(int[] values) {

    int n = values.length;
    int [][] memo = new int[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        memo[i][i] = values[i];

    for (int i = 0, j = 1; j < n; i++, j++)
        memo[i][j] = Math.max(values[i], values[j]);

    for (int k = 2; k < n; k++) {
        for (int i = 0,  j = k; j < n; i++, j++) {
            int a = values[i] + Math.min(memo[i + 2][j], memo[i + 1][j - 1]);
            int b = values[j] + Math.min(memo[i + 1][j - 1], memo[i][j - 2]);
            memo[i][j] = Math.max(a, b);
        }
    }

    return memo[0][n - 1];
}
```

Comment: You just pick the largest element, and the opponent does the same?

Comment: @Henrik4 A greedy approach doesn't work here, consider the following input [1, 2, 9, 2]. It's better for the first player to pick 1 in his first move, instead of the 2.

Comment: @Igor I would pick 9 on my first move.

Comment: @Henrik4 Please see the first sentence of the problem:
> Two players take turns choosing one of the *outer* coins.

Comment: @Igor What is an outer coin?

Comment: @Henrik4 I am sure my algorithm is correct for the result score. The problem I am facing is to print that optimal sequence out, I have done this successfully by pairs or ArrayList as mentioned, but the memory needed is too much for my task

Comment: Can you tell how big `n` is?

Comment: n is the number of element in array, so for arr{1,2,3,4} n would be 4. Maybe it was unclear what I wrote, I mean the memory space cannot exceed n^2 in big O notation

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is similar to [Predict the Winner of LeetCode (486)](https://leetcode.com/problems/predict-the-winner/) with some minor changes that you would want to make:

#### Java

```
class Solution {
    public boolean maxGain(int[] nums) {
        int length = nums.length;
        int[][] dp = new int[length][length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            dp[i][i] = nums[i];

        for (int l = 1; l < length; l++)
            for (int i = 0; i < length - l; i++) {
                int j = i + l;
                dp[i][j] = Math.max(nums[i] - dp[i + 1][j], nums[j] - dp[i][j - 1]);
            }

        return dp[0][length - 1] > -1;
    }
}
```

#### Python

```
class Solution:
    def max_gain(self, nums):
        length = len(nums)
        memo = [[-1 for _ in range(length)] for _ in range(length)]

        @functools.lru_cache(None)
        def f():
            def helper(nums, i, j):
                if i > j:
                    return 0

                if i == j:
                    return nums[i]

                if memo[i][j] != -1:
                    return memo[i][j]

                cur = max(nums[i] + min(helper(nums, i + 2, j), helper(nums, i + 1, j - 1)),
                          nums[j] + min(helper(nums, i, j - 2), helper(nums, i + 1, j - 1)))

                memo[i][j] = cur
                return cur

            score = helper(nums, 0, length - 1)
            total = sum(nums)
            return 2 * score >= total

        return f()
```

#### O(N) Memory

The space complexity might be an order of `N` for the second solution [provided in this link](https://leetcode.com/problems/predict-the-winner/discuss/96828/JAVA-9-lines-DP-solution-easy-to-understand-with-improvement-to-O(N)-space-complexity.):

```
class Solution {
    public boolean maxGain(int[] nums) {
        if (nums == null)
            return true;

        int length = nums.length;
        int[] dp = new int[length];

        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = i; j < length; j++) {
                if (i == j)
                    dp[i] = nums[i];

                else
                    dp[j] = Math.max(nums[i] - dp[j], nums[j] - dp[j - 1]);
            }
        }

        return dp[length - 1] > -1;
    }
}
```

#### Reference

[Most optimal solutions are here in the discussion board](https://leetcode.com/problems/predict-the-winner/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=)

Comment: this is not what I'm worrying, as I successfully calculated the score already, I will edit the question and add my src code, so that you guys will understand it better:)

Comment: i edited the question, i hope you will understand what i mean. Yes I'm looking for space complexity where the maximum is O(n^2)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, it's amazing that they optimmized it to O(N) complexity! And how would you print the optimal sequence out based on my src code? this is what i wanted to ask after all, for example the arr[4,7,2,3], the sequence in terms of index for an optimal result would be [3,0,1,2].